# Formato fecha en R

Tags: r

Estoy leyendo en formato .csv donde en una columna tengo unicamente años, por defecto R los lee en caracter. Pero necesito especificarlo como fecha de solo año. Estoy usando `read_delim` y especificando el tipo de columna usando `col_types = cols(col_date('%Y'))` pero los resultados que que arroja son por ejemplo:  **2021-01-01** así en cada registro del conjunto de datos. Y no sé que hacer para que me arroja solo el año. Agradezco si alguien me ayuda

Comment: Si es solo el año podrías leerlo con Int simplemente

Answer (score 0):

Lo que necesitas es utilizar el package `lubridate` y la función `year`.
Por ejemplo:

```
lubridate::year("2021-01-01")

output: 2021
```